# Calculate hours difference between today and 4/3/NextYear

Tags: php, datetime, mktime

I want to calculate the difference between today and next year April 4 (right now is 4/4/2013), but I don't know how to create a DateTime object using actual year + 1. This is what I have:

`$now = new DateTime();

$ref = mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, 3, date("Y")+1);

echo $diff = $ref->diff($now)->days;`

I think the problem is that mktime is not returning a DateTime object? Which is the best way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: One way is to find the date difference(*24 for hours) and subtract `systime` in hours.

Answer (score 1):

```
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$destination = date("Y-m-d" , mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, 3, date("Y")+1));

$todayObj = new DateTime($today);
$destObj = new DateTime($destination);

echo $diff = $todayObj->diff($destObj)->days;
```

Didn't test it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Use strtotime for this as below

```
$nextyear = date('Y')+1;
$time1=$nextyear.'-'.date('m').'-'.date('d');

$time2=date('Y-m-d');

echo $hourdiff = round((strtotime($time1) - strtotime($time2))/3600, 1);
```

Comment: it will not work when the current year will be 2013. In that case I will need to know the difference between the current day (in 2013) and 4-3-2014

Comment: @Tom it was example how to find hours between two dates. anyway see updated answer now

Comment: This is what i was looking for:
`$time1=date('Y')+1.'-'.date('m').'-'.date('d');`
I already know how to subtract days between two dates ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print_r(date_diff(date_create(), date_create('2013-04-03 00:00:00')));
```

Outputs:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 5
    [d] => 22
    [h] => 9
    [i] => 8
    [s] => 25
    [invert] => 0
    [days] => 173
)
```

Comment: and what happen when the current year is 2014? ;)

Comment: @Tom, `[invert]` field sets to one

Comment: @Tom, or like this: `print_r(date_diff(date_create('2013-04-04 00:00:00'), date_create()));`